# pandas: Find closest matching dataframe

Tags: algorithm, pandas

I am working on personal project (work on spare time, by myself) and would like to ask if anyone can propose simple strategies for finding a similar dataframe to a selected one.

I have dataframes describing daily events, like temperature and humidity, sampled every 10 minutes. I want to get a dataframe of a day, and find among the other daily dataframes the one the best resembles the one I am looking for.

Now I understand this is a VERY large topic, which could involve AI in the end of the day. I am hoping people can point me to a simple to implement strategies, like minimal square differences, or share directions, experiences and/or links.

If you do feel I should study entry level AI, please let me know. Because I am doing this completely solo, with limited time, I am willing to compromise on the end result in detriment of getting this done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple statistical approach would be to look at the correlation and/or covariance of the two data series.

Correlation : corr
Covariance : cov

See, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/computation.html#correlation for usage

Comment: Thanks, Alex, looks like a good idea. Thank you for helping on such a vague question.

Comment: Thank you, nitin. (Sorry about the previous misunderstanding about who answered the question. I was checking SO on my phone and the mobile site has a weird layout.)